# Script inside iframe is overriding main page's JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to use iframe to render an HTML document. That HTML Document can be anything, it's dynamic.

I have used jquery.min.js in my website. and HTML content i am rendering, contains import to jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js

`slim` version of jquery used in iframe is overriding jquery of main page. Which is resulting in `$.ajax is not a function`.

**How Can i restrict iframe to not override**

```
<script src="/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="some-id">
    #document
       <html>
           <head></head>
           <body>
               <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           </body>
       </html>
</iframe>
```

In JS file i used below to set my content

```
$('#modal-html').contents().find('body').html(myhtmlcode);
```

I tried using sandbox to block javascript execution. It's not working.